# How to make a specific attribute as an auto increment laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to make my attribute as an autoIncriment with the Id

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->decimal('price', 17, 6)->nullable();
        $table->string('photo');
        $table->decimal('reference')->autoIncrement()->unique()->from(1000)->unsigned();
        $table->boolean('active');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

i have created this function and i want to make the reference auto increment start from 1000 , when i migrate it nothing change in my database

Comment: There are several ways you can look into [Available Column Types](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#available-column-types) in the docs

Comment: Just use increment(“column-name”) in migrations reference: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-method-increments

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the `reference` field to an `unsignedInteger` first.

Example:

```php
$table->unsignedInteger('reference')->->autoIncrement()->unique()->from(1000);
```